# Yii Framework Date Range

Tags: mysql, date, yii

I have problem finding a date range in Yii, if the FROM_DATE: 2015-02-05 and to_date: 2015-02-10, in gridview only display the data with the date 05,06,07,08,09 and only dated 10-02 which does not appear. 
in another condition if i want search a range of date like this from_date : 2015-02-21 to_date: 2015-02-21, data with date 2015-02-21 shoud appear
how to resolve that problem ? an how it should be correct code?

model

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
if(!empty($this->from_date) && empty($this->to_date)){
        $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date'";
    }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && empty($this->from_date)){
        $criteria->condition="create_date <= '$this->to_date'";
    }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && !empty($this->from_date)){
        $criteria->condition="create_date >= '$this->from_date' and create_date<= '$this->to_date'";
    }
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('lokasi',$this->lokasi,true);
    $criteria->compare('satisfy_val',$this->satisfy_val,true);
    $criteria->compare('create_date',$this->create_date,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>array('create_date DESC',)),
            'pagination'=>array(
                    'PageSize'=>150
            ),
    ));
}
```

thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for search date range

```
if((isset($this->from_date) && trim($this->from_date) != "") && (isset($this->to_date) && trim($this->to_date) != "")){
        $criteria->condition = ' create_date>="'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->from_date)).'" AND create_date<="'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->to_date)).'"';
}
```

after using the above code your code looks:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    if((isset($this->from_date) && trim($this->from_date) != "") && (isset($this->to_date) && trim($this->to_date) != "")){
        $criteria->condition = ' create_date>="'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->from_date)).'" AND create_date<="'.date("Y-m-d",strtotime($this->to_date)).'"';
    }
    $criteria->compare('user_id',$this->user_id);
    $criteria->compare('lokasi',$this->lokasi,true);
    $criteria->compare('satisfy_val',$this->satisfy_val,true);
    $criteria->compare('create_date',$this->create_date,true);
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
       'criteria'=>$criteria,
       'sort'=>array(
       'defaultOrder'=>array('create_date DESC',)),
        'pagination'=>array(
                'PageSize'=>150
        ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help and and your responses. I've tried the code you created, but the result is the same
and strangely if your code is placed under $ criteria-> compare ('create_date', $ this-> create_date, true); search date range with  different from_date and to_date runs perfectly but grouping by user and lokasi not work. another condition with same from_date and to_end date does not work. how to resolve that ?

Comment: from_date and to to_date are separate column fields in your database?

Comment: no, only create_date column, from_date and to_date is a variabel. now, the problem was solved